# I need Mysql Query to Find available dates for the selected month and year excluding the dates taken from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, date, range

Could you please help.
I need to show available dates with in the range of dates Taken from table

I have a booking table. It contains mStartdate and end date

Read the table and and show all available dates excluding the dates taken from table for the selected month and year.

**booking Table**
    | Id | StartDate | EndDate   |
    | 1  |2020-03-05 | 2020-03-05|
    | 2  |2020-03-10 | 2020-03-11|
    | 3  |2020-03-12 | 2020-03-14|
    | 3  |2020-03-16 | 2020-03-18|

What I need is all the available dates for the month 03 ie March.
example

```
2020-03-01 t0 2020-03-04 is available
2020-03-06 t0 2020-03-09 is available
2020-03-15 t0 2020-03-15 is available
2020-03-19 t0 2020-03-31 is available
```

I want to make it little more clear that I want 
to read date from booking table for the Month March. Then Create a list of available dates Like

```
2020-03-01
2020-03-02
2020-03-03
2020-03-04
2020-03-06
2020-03-07
2020-03-08
2020-03-09
2020-03-15
2020-03-19
to
2020-03-31
```

Thank you friends. Please help me.

Comment: [Edit] the question and show the query you have tried and explain what the problems with it were.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.0, you could use a recursive common table expression to generate the list of dates of the month, then filter it with the date ranges defined in the table:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select '2020-03-01' dt
    union all select dt + interval 1 day 
    from cte
    where dt + interval 1 day < '2020-04-01'
)
select dt
from cte c
where not exists (select 1 from mytable t where c.dt between t.start_date and t.end_date)
order by dt
```

---

In earlier versions, one solution involves a table of numbers; here is a solution with a derived table

```
select '2020-03-01' + interval x.n day dt
from (select 0 n union all select 2 ... union all select 30) x
where not exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t
    where '2020-03-01' + interval x.n day between t.start_date and t.end_date
)
order by dt
```

Comment: I am using a lower version of MySql

Comment: @SenKMathew: I updated my answer with a solution for earlier versions.

Comment: Thank you GMB for you efforts. But the result was wrong. Take the scenario.> example bookin table contains a date range 2020-03-10 to 2020-03-12. so dates 10,11,12 not available. rest of dates for the month march are available. i want that list. another example is suppose two bookings were there. 2020-03-10 to 202003-12 and 2020-03-14 to 2020-03-15. In this case available dates will be 10,11,12 , 13 and rest of the dates for the month. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can using `UNION`for getting result from two columns. I just write query for one column. Same method apply for another column. 
**Methid 1**
Using `CAST()` method with MySql `BETWEEN` approach

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE StartDate BETWEEN CAST('2014-02-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2014-02-28' AS DATE);
```

**Method 2**
Using `CAST()` method without MySql `BETWEEN` approach

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE StartDate >= CAST('2014-02-01' AS DATE)
AND StartDate <= CAST('2014-02-28' AS DATE);
```

Comment: Thank you Dear Friend for your help. But I want the all the date of the month march excluding the the dates(Start date and end date and also range of dates)